# I need background-color for comment

Tags: css

I have 2 comments on http://11klassniki.ru/post_ccuz.php?id_ccuz=19. One of them is reply for first comment.
He has

```
#commentRoot li
{
    margin: 7px 0 7px 10px;
}
```

I tried to give him

```
background-color:blue;
```

but this color reflect for all comments. I need to give background-color only for replies.

**css**

```
ul 
{
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 700px;
}

#commentRoot li
{
    margin: 7px 0 7px 10px;
}

#commentRoot li a
{
   margin-left: 500px;
}

#commentRoot li .commentContent
{
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius:5px; -moz-border-radius:5px; -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    margin: 5px 10px;
    }
#commentRoot li h6 
{
    color: #085991;
}
#commentRoot li h6  span 
{
    color: #666; font-size: 11px;  
    margin-left: 20px;
    }
#commentRoot li .comment
{
    margin-top: 5px;
}
#commentRoot li a.reply
{
    font-size: 11px; 
}    

/*  Формочка */
#newComment, .loader {display: none;}
#cancelComment
{
    float: right; width: 20px; color: red; cursor: pointer;
}
#newComment input
{
    height: 26px; width: 250px; padding: 0 5px ; margin-left: 50px; 
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
}
#newComment textarea
{
    width: 350px;  height: 100px; margin-left: 5px; 
    vertical-align: middle; border: solid 1px #ccc;
}
#newComment button
{
    margin-left: 102px; margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Please can you give us a JSFiddle and explain your question more clearly?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like (check JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/queu8nzw/3/))

```
#commentRoot li .commentContent {
    border: none;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin: 5px 10px;
}


#commentRoot li ul li .commentContent {
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 5px 10px;
}
```

Comment: I need background color for 
#commentRoot li .commentContent {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 5px 10px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
} but only for second comment.

Comment: Hello @user3871018 I have updated my answer + JS Fiddle. I hope it helps!

Comment: Glad to hear that! It would be nice if you could vote my answer up! :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can try use specificity of the elements, like this:

```
#commentRoot li ul .commentContent {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Look a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/LaLc4ryb/